# When updating the transform of an SVG element, Firefox moves the clip-path while Chromium doesn't - which is right and what is a portable solution?

Tags: dom, svg, cross-browser

Firefox and Chromium have different behaviors when the transform of a clipped SVG element is updated. Firefox moves the clip path, whereas Chromium does not.

Example code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id='button'>Click to translate</button>
    <br/>
    <svg width='500px' height='500px'>
      <g clip-path='polygon(0 0, 50 0, 50 50, 0 50)'>
        <g transform='translate(25 25)' id='group'>
          <rect x='0' y='0' width='50' height='50' fill='red'></rect>
        </g>
      </g>
    </svg>
    <script>
      var b = document.getElementById('button');
      var g = document.getElementById('group');
      b.onclick = function(event) {
          g.setAttribute('transform', 'translate(0, 0)');
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/TheAspiringHacker/w7ymfn3s/1/

The outermost `g` element is clipped according to a square with side lengths of 50. To determine at what coordinates to place the clipping polygon, it seems that the browser finds the top left corner of the rectangle containing content to render. Since there is an inner `g` element translated (25, 25) containing a `rect` at (0, 0), the clipping polygon is placed at (25, 25).

When the button is clicked, the inner `g` element's transformation is changed so that it is at (0, 0).

Firefox and Chromium have different behaviors when the button is clicked. In Firefox, the clip path's location is correspondingly changed to match the new location of the rectangle. In Chromium, it isn't, causing a portion of the rectangle to be clipped. I have tested the code with Firefox 66.0.2 and Chromium 73.0.3683.86.

Which behavior is the correct behavior, according to the specification?

I want to clip an element that I programmatically translate. Considering that Firefox and Chromium seem to have different behavior, what solutions are there for me to get something that works cross-browser?

Comment: I think Firefox is right FWIW.

Comment: I think actually that both are wrong.  @enxaneta's solution using an SVG `<clipPath>` shows what should be happening.

Answer (score 1):

I would define the clipPath first:

```
<clipPath id="poly">
   <polygon points="0 0, 50 0, 50 50, 0 50"></polygon>
</clipPath>
```

then apply it to the group:

```
 <g clip-path="url(#poly)">
```

```js
var b = document.getElementById('button');
      var g = document.getElementById('group');
      b.onclick = function(event) {
          g.setAttributeNS(null,'transform', 'translate(0, 0)');
      };
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
    <button id='button'>Click to translate</button>
    <br/>
    <svg width='500px' height='500px'>
    <clipPath id="poly">
      <polygon points="0 0, 50 0, 50 50, 0 50"></polygon>
    </clipPath>
    <g clip-path="url(#poly)">
        <g transform='translate(25 25)' id='group'>
          <rect x='0' y='0' width='50' height='50' fill='red'></rect>
        </g>
      </g>
      

    </svg>
```